# plotting a scatter graph in wx.lib.plot

Tags: wxpython

I am wanting to draw a scatter graph in wxpython
so far i have managed to draw a line graph. I do not now how to draw a scatter graph using wx.lib.plot
any help would be appreciated

```
import wx
import logging
import wx.lib.plot as plot

class PlotCanvasExample(plot.PlotCanvas):
def __init__(self, parent, id, size):
    ''' Initialization routine for the this panel.'''
    plot.PlotCanvas.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.BORDER_NONE, size=desiredSize)
    self.data = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,5), (4,6), (5,8), (6,8), (10,10)]
    line = plot.PolyLine(self.data, legend='', colour='pink', width=2)
    gc = plot.PlotGraphics([line], 'Line Graph', 'X Axis', 'Y Axis')
    self.Draw(gc, xAxis=(0,15), yAxis=(0,15))

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, id ,size):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size=desiredSize)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.canvas = PlotCanvasExample(self, 0, size)
    sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
''' Simple main program to display this panel. '''
# Create a simple wxFrame to insert the panel into
desiredSize = wx.Size(300,200)
app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MyFrame(None, -1,  size=desiredSize)    
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
plot.PolyLine(self.data, legend='', colour='pink', width=2)
```

with

```
plot.PolyMarker(self.data, legend='', marker='circle', colour='pink', width=2)
```

refer
http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.plot.PolyMarker-class.html